# Round off Value in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to round off my value with some constraints. For example..

```
1. Value - 5.89
   Required solution  - 6.29
```

It's time difference value, which needs be rounded after every decimal value as 0.60. whenever, my decimal values reached at 60, it should rounded to the next value and remaining decimal value above 60, needs to be as it is.

Please suggest.

Comment: So you mean 5.89 means 5 minutes and 89 seconds, equals to 6 minutes and 29 seconds?

Comment: Use interval data type, and the problem is gone.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Correct. 5.89, equals to 6.29.  And i am using Sql Server.

Comment: Using a decimal data type here is just going to cause confusion and the opportunity for mistakes to creep in. I'd strongly suggest just using an integer that keeps a simple count of (whatever the smallest unit you're working with here - is it seconds or minutes?). Do the conversion into multiple units only immediately before presenting it for display.

Comment: It's Minutes. Actually, I am taking difference of two timing(Out time - In time)  and output, i am subtracting with OT hours, which is in decimal like 8.30. For example. - if Out time - In time is 14.15 hours and OT is 8.30 hours. system calculates output as 5.85, while i need out put as 5.45 hours. Please suggest

Comment: But what about 14.05 - 8.55 ? Your decimal calculated value is 5.50. Which is under .60, so I guess that's right, right? That there are 5 hours and 50 minutes between those two times. And not, say, 5 hours and 10 minutes? This is why I'd suggest using a data type that, unambiguously, cannot contain erroneous values that you then have to apply corrections for.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me in MS ACCESS

```
   select Format(YourField \ 60, '0') & '.' & Format(YourField Mod 60, '00') as [YourField] from YourTable
```

for SQL SERVER Try This,

```
select Right('0' + cast(YourField / 60) %60 as varchar),2)+ ':'+
right('0' + cast(YourField %60 as varchar),2 ) from YourTable
```

Comment: The question is tagged `sql` to answers should contain standard SQL